# How to include comfirm box in Php

Tags: javascript, php, joomla3.0, joomla1.5

I have created a Joomla article. I have installed sourcerer Joomla extension to use JavaScript and php. I am working on course purchase site in this user purchase course from owner and credits are deducted on purchasing of course. We are using a confirm box so that when a user click on "Cancel" button then it return to course page and when user click on "OK" button, then a php code is executed and course is purchased and credits are deducted. It works fine when I click on the OK button. When I click on cancel button, it is deducted credits also. I don't want to deduct credits on click of cancel.

I am using this JavaScript code:

```
var answer = confirm ("You are about to purchase this course. Click Continue to complete the purchase, or CANCEL to return to the CE page.");
if(!answer)
{
    window.location="index.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
function confirm_delete() {
      return confirm('are you sure?');
    }
```

Use onclick in the button

```
onclick='return confirm_delete()'
```

When the user clicks OK the php code gets excecuted but when clicked on Cancel nothing happends.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use onclick?

onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"

Comment: Please  have a look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by onclick method as follows:

```
oncllick ='return confirm()'

function confirm()
{
    return confirm('Are you sure to continue?');
}
```

when user click ok then code excecuted and when click on cancel button it remains on that page only